# Help with poisson distribution confused / lack information

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

If $E(X) \sim \mathsf{Poisson}(\lambda),$ what is

a) $P(X=2)$

b) $P(X>2)$

c) $P(X^2>2)$

I don't understand what this is trying to say and I don't see how I calculate the Poisson when I'm only given that information. Please help!

Comment: As a hint for b, because the distribution is discrete $P(X>2)=P(X\geq 3) = 1-P(X\leq 2) = 1 - F_X(2)$ where $F_X(\cdot)$ is the cdf of $X$. For c, it is similar, but note that $X^2>2$ if, and only if, $X\geq 2$.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, a random variable $X \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ has pmf
\begin{equation*}
f_X(x)=P(X=x)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}, \text{ where } x \in \{0,1,\dots\}
\end{equation*}
If you are not given a specific value for $\lambda$, you answers will just be in terms of $\lambda$. Can you answer your questions now?

Comment: Yes that helped thanks !